# How to concatenate a string using a for loop n times?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a `variable = "v"`. I would like to concatenate to this variable as many `v` as input by the user. So, if the user enters 10, the output would be `vvvvvvvvv`. Although I have it working as defined, I'm not sure if this is the right approach because I have to use a for loop to concatenate as many `v` as required to the original variable created in step 1 and then print the variable from step 1.

This is what I have so far:

1. Create a variable equal to the string `"v"`;
2. Ask how many ‘waves’ the user would like printed;
3. Using a `for` loop, concatenate as many `v` as necessary to the variable created in step 1;
4. After the loop has been completed, print the variable from step 1.

```py
variable = "v"
waves = int(input("How many waves would you like to print?: "))
for i in range(waves):
    print(variable, end="")
```

Comment: `print(variable * waves)`.  If you multiply a string by a number, it repeats the string.  No loop required.  You can assign the result to another variable as well.

Comment: or ``variable = variable*waves`` and then ``print(variable)``

Comment: then what's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop to accumulate more of the variable

```
variable = "v"
waves = int(input("How many waves would you like to print?: "))
for i in range(waves-1):
    variable+="v"
print(variable)
```

Or you could more directly increase the variable to the appropriate length without looping.

```
variable = "v"
waves = int(input("How many waves would you like to print?: "))
variable*=waves
print(variable)
```

Comment: The first step requires that I define a variable equal to the string 'v'

Comment: @Noobie just to clarify, do you want to `waves` many "v" to variable or is that the total amount? Your example gives an input of 10 and prints 10 v's, but if you want to concatenate onto an initial "v", an input of 10 should print 11 v's

Comment: That would be the total amount

Answer (score 1):

yes i think your answer is correct. also you can use like this

```
variable = "v"
waves = int(input("How many waves would you like to print?: "))
print(variable*waves)
```

try this

Comment: OP has specified they have to use a for loop.

Comment: Most effective: without a `for` loop